# Wifi Speed Very Slow Compared to Win10

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, atheros

I dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. The wifi speed on Ubuntu is severely lower than what it should be compared to Windows. I'm new to using Linux and am having trouble fixing this.
I don't know what information would be helpful in solving this, so if anything else is needed just ask. Any and all help is appreciated!

Output `lspci | grep Network`

`02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)`

Kernel Version

`5.8.0-38-generic` and no change when using `5.4.91-050491-generic`

Output `sudo lshw`

````
*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
                version: 31
                serial: 3c:95:09:e8:8e:d1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.8.0-38-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.40.19 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:131 memory:b1000000-b11fffff
    ```
````

Comment: How do you measure speed?

Comment: When I am downloading things from the terminal it shows the download speed as only several hundred Kb/s. Additionally the network settings show the speed as about 1 Mb/s when it's 72Mb/s in Windows.

Comment: Do you know the difference between megabytes and megabits? You need to check speed the same way on both systems to be able to tell something. Not just "download something".

Comment: I tried to do a speedtest on speedtest.net but it won't even connect to the servers to start it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Is it the same computer where Windows and Ubuntu is installed. Is Windows Fast Startup feature disabled in Windows?

Comment: I dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu, and fast startup is disabled.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. I suggest to boot with a 5.4 kernel and test how it works. You can also report a bug.